# Access violation MATLAB

Tags: java, mysql, matlab

My program keeps crashing after a while. Basically I am fetching data from a MySQL database and writing to it using ODBC. My program is compiled using the MATLAB's compiler and running the .exe through the runtime.

Everything seems to run fine, but after a while (usually a few hours or days later) the program will crash and I will get an error saying something about access violation. What could the problem be? This is what I am getting...

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
          Access violation detected at Mon Feb 29 14:06:03 2016
------------------------------------------------------------------------

Configuration:
  Crash Decoding      : Disabled
  Crash Mode          : continue (default)
  Current Graphics Driver: Unknown hardware 
  Default Encoding    : windows-1252
  Graphics card 1     : (Standard display types) ( 0x1013 ) Microsoft Basic Display Adapter Version 6.3.9600.16384
  Host Name           : WIN-ATLIEC7GTB3
  MATLAB Architecture : win64
  MATLAB Root         : C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85
  MATLAB Version      : 8.5.0.197613 (R2015a)
  OpenGL              : hardware
  Operating System    : Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard
  Processor ID        : x86 Family 6 Model 62 Stepping 4, GenuineIntel
  Virtual Machine     : Java 1.7.0_60-b19 with Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode
  Window System       : Version 6.3 (Build 9600)

Fault Count: 1


Abnormal termination:
Access violation

Register State (from fault):
  RAX = 0000000000000000  RBX = 0000000000000000
  RCX = 00000000040a0000  RDX = 0000000000000000
  RSP = 000000000e006cb0  RBP = 0000000000000000
  RSI = 0000000000000000  RDI = 000000007c2c4190

   R8 = 0000000000000000   R9 = 0000000000000000
  R10 = 000000007c2c4190  R11 = 000000000e006c80
  R12 = 0000000000000000  R13 = 0000000000000003
  R14 = 00000000042fe920  R15 = 00000000042fedb0

  RIP = 00007ff92d12539c  EFL = 00010246

   CS = 0033   FS = 0053   GS = 002b

Stack Trace (from fault):
[  0] 0x00007ff92d12539c c:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector ODBC 5.3\myodbc5a.dll+00086940 SQLFetchScroll+00080984
[  1] 0x00007ff92d694d41                     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ODBC32.dll+00019777 ODBCSetTryWaitValue+00001153
[  2] 0x00007ff92d69bc6e                     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ODBC32.dll+00048238 SQLAllocHandle+00000158
[  3] 0x000000005ea6cec4 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\dodbc.dll+00052932
[  4] 0x000000005ea6dc10 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\dodbc.dll+00056336
[  5] 0x000000000e125978 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\mcos_impl.dll+00088440
[  6] 0x000000000e1328fe C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\mcos_impl.dll+00141566
[  7] 0x000000000e131356 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\mcos_impl.dll+00136022
[  8] 0x000000000e13f047 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\mcos_impl.dll+00192583
[  9] 0x000000000e13ef03 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\mcos_impl.dll+00192259
[ 10] 0x0000000007922ce4 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00077028 Mfh_MATLAB_fn::dispatch_fh+00000452
[ 11] 0x000000000e156dd0 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\mcos_impl.dll+00290256
[ 12] 0x0000000007922a7e C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00076414 Mfunction_handle::dispatch+00000766
[ 13] 0x0000000006b44569 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00083305 in_is_matlab_function+00027929
[ 14] 0x0000000006b43d52 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00081234 in_is_matlab_function+00025858
[ 15] 0x0000000006b4333f C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00078655 in_is_matlab_function+00023279
[ 16] 0x0000000006b42eef C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00077551 in_is_matlab_function+00022175
[ 17] 0x0000000006b4bdcb C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00114123 in_is_matlab_function+00058747
[ 18] 0x0000000006b4a09c C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00106652 in_is_matlab_function+00051276
[ 19] 0x0000000006c1684f C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00944207 MathWorks::MException::MExceptionEnvelope::MCOSClassID+00000991
[ 20] 0x0000000006c167b1 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00944049 MathWorks::MException::MExceptionEnvelope::MCOSClassID+00000833
[ 21] 0x0000000006b8da75 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00383605 inGetCurrentWS+00155269
[ 22] 0x0000000006b8ce8c C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00380556 inGetCurrentWS+00152220
[ 23] 0x0000000006b8b6e9 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00374505 inGetCurrentWS+00146169
[ 24] 0x0000000007922694 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00075412 Mfh_file::dispatch_fh+00000548
[ 25] 0x0000000007922a7e C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00076414 Mfunction_handle::dispatch+00000766
[ 26] 0x000000000e12791e C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\mcos_impl.dll+00096542
[ 27] 0x0000000007922ce4 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00077028 Mfh_MATLAB_fn::dispatch_fh+00000452
[ 28] 0x000000000e156dd0 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\mcos_impl.dll+00290256
[ 29] 0x0000000007922a7e C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00076414 Mfunction_handle::dispatch+00000766
[ 30] 0x0000000006b49597 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00103831 in_is_matlab_function+00048455
[ 31] 0x0000000006b4a1ab C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00106923 in_is_matlab_function+00051547
[ 32] 0x0000000006c1684f C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00944207 MathWorks::MException::MExceptionEnvelope::MCOSClassID+00000991
[ 33] 0x0000000006c167b1 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00944049 MathWorks::MException::MExceptionEnvelope::MCOSClassID+00000833
[ 34] 0x0000000006b8da75 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00383605 inGetCurrentWS+00155269
[ 35] 0x0000000006b8ce8c C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00380556 inGetCurrentWS+00152220
[ 36] 0x0000000006b8b6e9 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00374505 inGetCurrentWS+00146169
[ 37] 0x0000000007922694 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00075412 Mfh_file::dispatch_fh+00000548
[ 38] 0x0000000007922a7e C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00076414 Mfunction_handle::dispatch+00000766
[ 39] 0x000000000e12791e C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\mcos_impl.dll+00096542
[ 40] 0x0000000007922ce4 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00077028 Mfh_MATLAB_fn::dispatch_fh+00000452
[ 41] 0x000000000e156dd0 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\mcos_impl.dll+00290256
[ 42] 0x0000000007922a7e C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00076414 Mfunction_handle::dispatch+00000766
[ 43] 0x0000000006b44569 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00083305 in_is_matlab_function+00027929
[ 44] 0x0000000006b43d52 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00081234 in_is_matlab_function+00025858
[ 45] 0x0000000006b4333f C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00078655 in_is_matlab_function+00023279
[ 46] 0x0000000006b42eef C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00077551 in_is_matlab_function+00022175
[ 47] 0x0000000006b4bdcb C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00114123 in_is_matlab_function+00058747
[ 48] 0x0000000006b4a09c C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00106652 in_is_matlab_function+00051276
[ 49] 0x0000000006c1684f C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00944207 MathWorks::MException::MExceptionEnvelope::MCOSClassID+00000991
[ 50] 0x0000000006c167b1 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00944049 MathWorks::MException::MExceptionEnvelope::MCOSClassID+00000833
[ 51] 0x0000000006b8da75 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00383605 inGetCurrentWS+00155269
[ 52] 0x0000000006b8ce8c C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00380556 inGetCurrentWS+00152220
[ 53] 0x0000000006b8b6e9 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00374505 inGetCurrentWS+00146169
[ 54] 0x0000000007922694 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00075412 Mfh_file::dispatch_fh+00000548
[ 55] 0x0000000007922a7e C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00076414 Mfunction_handle::dispatch+00000766
[ 56] 0x000000000e12791e C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\mcos_impl.dll+00096542
[ 57] 0x0000000007922ce4 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00077028 Mfh_MATLAB_fn::dispatch_fh+00000452
[ 58] 0x000000000e156dd0 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\mcos_impl.dll+00290256
[ 59] 0x0000000007922a7e C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00076414 Mfunction_handle::dispatch+00000766
[ 60] 0x0000000006b44569 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00083305 in_is_matlab_function+00027929
[ 61] 0x0000000006b43d52 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00081234 in_is_matlab_function+00025858
[ 62] 0x0000000006b4333f C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00078655 in_is_matlab_function+00023279
[ 63] 0x0000000006b42eef C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00077551 in_is_matlab_function+00022175
[ 64] 0x0000000006b4bdcb C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00114123 in_is_matlab_function+00058747
[ 65] 0x0000000006b4a09c C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00106652 in_is_matlab_function+00051276
[ 66] 0x0000000006c1684f C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00944207 MathWorks::MException::MExceptionEnvelope::MCOSClassID+00000991
[ 67] 0x0000000006c167b1 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00944049 MathWorks::MException::MExceptionEnvelope::MCOSClassID+00000833
[ 68] 0x0000000006b8da75 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00383605 inGetCurrentWS+00155269
[ 69] 0x0000000006b8ce8c C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00380556 inGetCurrentWS+00152220
[ 70] 0x0000000006b8b6e9 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00374505 inGetCurrentWS+00146169
[ 71] 0x0000000007922694 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00075412 Mfh_file::dispatch_fh+00000548
[ 72] 0x0000000007922a7e C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00076414 Mfunction_handle::dispatch+00000766
[ 73] 0x0000000006b49597 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00103831 in_is_matlab_function+00048455
[ 74] 0x0000000006b4a1ab C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00106923 in_is_matlab_function+00051547
[ 75] 0x0000000006c1684f C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00944207 MathWorks::MException::MExceptionEnvelope::MCOSClassID+00000991
[ 76] 0x0000000006c167b1 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00944049 MathWorks::MException::MExceptionEnvelope::MCOSClassID+00000833
[ 77] 0x0000000006b8da75 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00383605 inGetCurrentWS+00155269
[ 78] 0x0000000006b8ce8c C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00380556 inGetCurrentWS+00152220
[ 79] 0x0000000006b8b6e9 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00374505 inGetCurrentWS+00146169
[ 80] 0x0000000007922694 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00075412 Mfh_file::dispatch_fh+00000548
[ 81] 0x0000000007922a7e C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00076414 Mfunction_handle::dispatch+00000766
[ 82] 0x0000000006b49597 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00103831 in_is_matlab_function+00048455
[ 83] 0x0000000006b4a1ab C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00106923 in_is_matlab_function+00051547
[ 84] 0x0000000006c1684f C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00944207 MathWorks::MException::MExceptionEnvelope::MCOSClassID+00000991
[ 85] 0x0000000006c167b1 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00944049 MathWorks::MException::MExceptionEnvelope::MCOSClassID+00000833
[ 86] 0x0000000006b8da75 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00383605 inGetCurrentWS+00155269
[ 87] 0x0000000006b8ce8c C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00380556 inGetCurrentWS+00152220
[ 88] 0x0000000006b8b6e9 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00374505 inGetCurrentWS+00146169
[ 89] 0x0000000007922694 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00075412 Mfh_file::dispatch_fh+00000548
[ 90] 0x0000000007922a7e C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00076414 Mfunction_handle::dispatch+00000766
[ 91] 0x0000000006b86ca6 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00355494 inGetCurrentWS+00127158
[ 92] 0x0000000006b86414 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00353300 inGetCurrentWS+00124964
[ 93] 0x0000000006b8c64c C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00378444 inGetCurrentWS+00150108
[ 94] 0x0000000006b8bcd5 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00376021 inGetCurrentWS+00147685
[ 95] 0x0000000006b4f19c C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00127388 in_is_matlab_function+00072012
[ 96] 0x0000000006b49f95 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00106389 in_is_matlab_function+00051013
[ 97] 0x0000000006c1684f C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00944207 MathWorks::MException::MExceptionEnvelope::MCOSClassID+00000991
[ 98] 0x0000000006c167b1 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00944049 MathWorks::MException::MExceptionEnvelope::MCOSClassID+00000833
[ 99] 0x0000000006b8da75 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00383605 inGetCurrentWS+00155269
[100] 0x0000000006b8ce8c C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00380556 inGetCurrentWS+00152220
[101] 0x0000000006b8b6e9 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00374505 inGetCurrentWS+00146169
[102] 0x0000000007922757 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00075607 Mfh_file::dispatch_fh+00000743
[103] 0x0000000007922a7e C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00076414 Mfunction_handle::dispatch+00000766
[104] 0x0000000006b3be56 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00048726 inCallFcn+00000230
[105] 0x0000000006b3bdb7 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00048567 inCallFcn+00000071
[106] 0x0000000006b3bca0 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00048288 inPushCheckpoint+00000176
[107] 0x0000000006b3bbd1 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00048081 inCallFcnWithTrap+00000081
[108] 0x0000000006d369ce C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+02124238 InterpEnterDebugMode::~InterpEnterDebugMode+00114158
[109] 0x0000000006cd2d97 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+01715607 inCallFcnWithTrapInDesiredWSAndPublishEvents+00000071
[110] 0x0000000007479712 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\iqm.dll+00235282 iqm::BaseFEvalPlugin::inCallFcnWithTrap+00000066
[111] 0x0000000007479359 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\iqm.dll+00234329 iqm::BaseFEvalPlugin::execute+00000313
[112] 0x00000000fd0ba094 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\mcr.dll+00237716 mcrRegisterExternalFunction+00014692
[113] 0x0000000007474e9a C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\iqm.dll+00216730 iqm::Iqm::setupIqmFcnPtrs+00027338
[114] 0x0000000007474d86 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\iqm.dll+00216454 iqm::Iqm::setupIqmFcnPtrs+00027062
[115] 0x0000000007465353 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\iqm.dll+00152403 iqm::Iqm::deliver+00003379
[116] 0x00000000fab5d216 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\uiw.dll+00512534 UIW_AttachThreadInput+00001270
[117] 0x00000000fab5caa5 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\uiw.dll+00510629 wsd_to_MSW+00004373
[118] 0x00000000fab5cb29 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\bin\win64\uiw.dll+00510761 wsd_to_MSW+00004505
[119] 0x00007ff94bf4081a                     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll+00591898 BroadcastSystemMessageExA+00000586
[120] 0x00007ff94beb33bf                     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll+00013247 PostMessageW+00001119
[121] 0x00007ff94beb3436                     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll+00013366 Post
```

Comment: Any native code (mex functions) you implemented yourself?

Comment: Nope, nothing I implemented on my own, except for the program (.m files) itself

Comment: Then you hit a bug in MATLAB, contact the support.